# Query Function outputs - Single type data : google Appscript : Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
 =QUERY(Importrange ("XYZ", "Sheet1!A15:AH"), "SELECT * where Col1 ='Pune'")
```

When I run this on different sheet, It removes elements from column of Different type for example
there is Column in Main sheet containing (4/2/14, 3/2/14,6/2/14,X,3/1/14) when i use this importRange with query it appears in new sheet as (4/2/14, 3/2/14,6/2/14, ,3/1/14) without X.

I corrected this Problem by setting the data as Plaintext then X started appearing but couldnt find function which does that because the mainsheet updates daily so i need to automate this task.

Comment: So, under the **Format** menu, you choose **Number**, then **Plain Text**?  And you want to know how do do this in code?  There is a [SetNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=fr-FR#setNumberFormat(String)) method.  But I'm not sure if that can be used to set the column to Plain Text

Comment: I have used CopyFormatToRange() to paste plain text format on a Range but that creates Havoc on Dates - if they are 2/3/14 they turn to something like 344555.98 where as using format menu converting to plain text it does happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an issue with the QUERY function not handling the cells with formatting well -- IMPORTRANGE is capable of moving all the cells over correctly.

Unfortunately, there isn't currently a method in Apps Script that allows the format of a cell to be set to Plain Text.

You have a few options for workarounds, depending on what your needs are:

1. Avoid the use of QUERY.  Use IMPORTRANGE to get all of the data you need into a local (scratch) worksheet, then build an Apps Script script to parse through that data, filter it to get the data you want, and then place that in the target sheet.
2. Avoid the use of QUERY and IMPORTRANGE.  Just use an Apps Script script to fetch the data you want from the source sheet and place it where you want in the target. This is probably the most direct approach.

If you haven't already, you might want to report the problem with QUERY to Google (Spreadsheet Help > Report an issue) -- eventually if the function is corrected you may not need Apps Script here.

Comment: I have no Hope on google now. Despite so many open cases & limitations of Import range screwing up they havent done a thing to revive it. and writing a appscript every time is beats to purpose of built in function. I would simply hard code every cell. any ways thanks for replying.